# How to embed elements between 2 siblings in a new elemt replacing the siblings via XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Having the following XML:

```xml
<body>
    <p class="infobox_start" />
    <h1>Header Inside</h1>
    <p>A paragraph inside an infobox</p>
    <ul>
        <li>Item One Inside</li>
        <li>Item Two Inside</li>
    </ul>
    <p class="infobox_end" />
    <p>A paragraph outside of an infobox</p>
    <h1>Header Outside</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>Item One Outside</li>
        <li>Item Two Outside</li>
    </ul>
    <p class="infobox_start" />
    <h1>Header B Inside</h1>
    <p>A paragraph inside an infobox</p>
    <ul>
        <li>Item A Inside</li>
        <li>Item B Inside</li>
    </ul>
    <p class="infobox_end" />
</body>
```

I would like to get:

```xml
<body>
    <div class="infobox">
        <h1>Header Inside</h1>
        <p>A paragraph inside an infobox</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Item One Inside</li>
            <li>Item Two Inside</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <p>A paragraph outside of an infobox</p>
    <h1>Header Outside</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>Item One Outside</li>
        <li>Item Two Outside</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="infobox">
        <h1>Header B Inside</h1>
        <p>A paragraph inside an infobox</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Item A Inside</li>
            <li>Item B Inside</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

that means I want to wrap what is in between `class="infobox_start"` and `class="infobox_end"` paragraphs into `div` elements, replacing these 2 placeholder paragraphs.

The XSLT with which I tried to achieve this (XSLT 2.0) is:

```
    <xsl:template match="/body">
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </body>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/body/p[@class='infobox_start']">
        <xsl:variable name="infostart" select="." />
        <xsl:variable name="infoend" select="./following-sibling::p[@class='infobox_end'][1]" />
        <div>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$infostart/following::*[. &lt;&lt; $infoend]" />
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="h1">
        <h1><xsl:apply-templates /></h1>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="p">
        <p><xsl:apply-templates /></p>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="ul">
        <ul><xsl:apply-templates /></ul>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="li">
        <li><xsl:apply-templates /></li>
    </xsl:template>
```

Unfortunately, the result ist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Header Inside</h1>
        <p>A paragraph inside an infobox</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Item One Inside</li>
            <li>Item Two Inside</li>
        </ul>
        <li>Item One Inside</li>
        <li>Item Two Inside</li>
    </div>
    <h1>Header Inside</h1>
    <p>A paragraph inside an infobox</p>
    <ul>
        <li>Item One Inside</li>
        <li>Item Two Inside</li>
    </ul>
    <p/>
    <p>A paragraph outside of an infobox</p>
    <h1>Header Outside</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>Item One Outside</li>
        <li>Item Two Outside</li>
    </ul>
    <div>
        <h1>Header B Inside</h1>
        <p>A paragraph inside an infobox</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Item A Inside</li>
            <li>Item B Inside</li>
        </ul>
        <li>Item A Inside</li>
        <li>Item B Inside</li>
    </div>
    <h1>Header B Inside</h1>
    <p>A paragraph inside an infobox</p>
    <ul>
        <li>Item A Inside</li>
        <li>Item B Inside</li>
    </ul>
    <p/>
</body>
```

While I managed to replace the placeholder paragraphs and embed the content into divs, the problem is that with this 'solution' templates are applied 2-times to the list items inside div-elements and two times to the whole content between the placeholders. What solution would deliver me the desired result shown above without the whole repition?

Comment: It is not clear where/how you use XPath to wrap elements into a `div`, this normally requires XQuery or XSLT, but your path does select the right elements and with normal `copy-of` you will certainly not lose any descendants. At https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVhEaiD I have inserted your XPath in XSLT (the `<<` has to be expressed in XML as `&lt;&lt;`) but then the content is selected. So you will need to elaborate in your question which tools you use for XPath or show more details as to where the content of the `ul` is lost.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I elaborated the example a bit further. Unfortunately, it became a little bit verbose but I do not know how provide the required context with less.

Answer (score 0):

I think, as soon as you want to process several such elements and wrap contents, it is a task for `for-each-group group-starting-with/group-ending-with`, [here as an XSLT 3 sample](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/?xslt=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%0D%0A%20%20expand-text%3D%22yes%22%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Amode%20on-no-match%3D%22shallow-copy%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22body%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acopy%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Afor-each-group%20select%3D%22*%22%20group-starting-with%3D%22p%5B%40class%20%3D%20%27infobox_start%27%5D%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Achoose%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Awhen%20test%3D%22self%3A%3Ap%5B%40class%20%3D%20%27infobox_start%27%5D%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Afor-each-group%20select%3D%22current-group%28%29%22%20group-ending-with%3D%22p%5B%40class%20%3D%20%27infobox_end%27%5D%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Achoose%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Awhen%20test%3D%22current-group%28%29%5Blast%28%29%5D%5Bself%3A%3Ap%5B%40class%20%3D%20%27infobox_end%27%5D%5D%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22infobox%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22current-group%28%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Awhen%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aotherwise%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22current-group%28%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aotherwise%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Achoose%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Afor-each-group%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Awhen%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aotherwise%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22current-group%28%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aotherwise%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Achoose%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Afor-each-group%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Acopy%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22p%5B%40class%20%3D%20%28%27infobox_start%27%2C%20%27infobox_end%27%29%5D%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0D%0A&input=%3Cbody%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cp%20class%3D%22infobox_start%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ch1%3EHeader%20Inside%3C%2Fh1%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cp%3EA%20paragraph%20inside%20an%20infobox%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cul%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3EItem%20One%20Inside%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3EItem%20Two%20Inside%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ful%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cp%20class%3D%22infobox_end%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cp%3EA%20paragraph%20outside%20of%20an%20infobox%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ch1%3EHeader%20Outside%3C%2Fh1%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cul%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3EItem%20One%20Outside%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3EItem%20Two%20Outside%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ful%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cp%20class%3D%22infobox_start%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ch1%3EHeader%20B%20Inside%3C%2Fh1%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cp%3EA%20paragraph%20inside%20an%20infobox%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cul%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3EItem%20A%20Inside%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cli%3EItem%20B%20Inside%3C%2Fli%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ful%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cp%20class%3D%22infobox_end%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fbody%3E&input-type=XML):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="body">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="p[@class = 'infobox_start']">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="self::p[@class = 'infobox_start']">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-ending-with="p[@class = 'infobox_end']">
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="current-group()[last()][self::p[@class = 'infobox_end']]">
                  <div class="infobox">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                  </div>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:
template>
  
  <xsl:template match="p[@class = ('infobox_start', 'infobox_end')]"/>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For an XSLT 2 processor like older versions of Saxon 9 you would need to remove the `xsl:mode` declaration and spell out the identity transformation template instead.